# Virtual / on-screen keyboard for browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, keyboard, accessibility

I am working on a SPA which is going to run on a browser to support a digital kiosk. I am exploring the virtual/on-screen keyboard options and while I was determined to go with [simple keyboard](https://github.com/hodgef/simple-keyboard), I found out that on Linux, when I use the touch screen, Mozilla displays a virtual, on screen keyboard which works and looks pretty well (on the other hand, simple-keyboard needs a lot of tuning and coding). Is there a universal option to have this on all browsers and I am missing it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering why you tagged this question with accessibility?

Comment: I tagged it with accessibility because I was wondering whether the answer was hidden  in an accessibility keyboard which could be provided from browsers.

Comment: I see, and you're right: Gnome desktop has this option. You can activate the on-screen keyboard in the system accessibility settings, even if you don't have a touch screen. You'll have to use the mouse then to type. For windows, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, web technologies don't offer you a way to force a touch screen keyboard, but the operating system (OS) does, and you should use it. A JavaScript solution will always be more volatile and less fast.

You might want to use a touch screen laptop to test your application. (:

A responsive web app should allow for multi-modal input, meaning users should be able to switch input mode while using the app, f.e. from mouse to keyboard, or from physical keyboard to on-screen-keyboard. This is also an upcoming accessibility requirement in [WCAG 2.2 Concurrent Input Mechanisms](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/concurrent-input-mechanisms.html)

We have a lot of assumptions about input methods based on devices, but a smartphone user can attach a bluetooth keyboard or mouse, and might actually need to.

This is why the web technologies do not provide "universal options" to trigger a touch screen keyboard. Instead, it puts that decision off to the platform (Browser and OS), which has more knowledge about the hardware used.

To further illustrate this concept: the [HTML attribute `inputmode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode) along with the `type` attribute help the browser optimise the on-screen keyboard, *if displayed*. But does not decide whether to display one or not.

If the OS supports the device's touch screen, it should display a on-screen keyboard once you set focus inside an input, maybe by means of touch. Whether or not the keyboard will respect the `inputmode`, depends on the browser-OS combination.

If you are able to specify the used hardware for the kiosk, you could recommend an OS that does.